# Facebook Live API - how to test a desktop application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, air, facebook-live-api

I have:

1. Facebook application in the "development" mode with the Live-API feature (non-approved yet);
2. Desktop application with Facebook oAuth login (works ok, Mac/PC).

I can't start any live stream because always getting the error:
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video)

URL
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{page_id}/live_videos

```
{
"access_token": "{access_token_from_oauth}",
"description": "Test description",
"title" : "Test title",
"status": "LIVE_NOW"
```

}

---

```
"error": {
    "message": "(#200) App does not have permission to create live video on this user",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "FEJ5AhneYP2"
}
```

I've tested with 3 admins for that Facebook-app, and have the same result. How I can test API Live video in the "development mode" and without accepted (by Facebook) permissions?
Thanx

**RESOLVED**
The full list of permissions is and it's working for all admins/test users:
"publish_actions", // user, group
"manage_pages", "publish_pages", // user page
"user_managed_groups",
"user_friends",
"public_profile",
"user_actions.video" // notifications for friends

Comment: Check if the access token contains `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permission. If these permissions are missing, you will not be able to make the API call. You can use the Access Token Debugger tool to check permissions in your access token: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Docs on the permissions needed can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/

Comment: My permissions are: manage_pages,public_profile,user_videos,user_actions.video,user_managed_groups

Comment: If the users are admins, developers, or testers of the application, they can use your application.  Your application then just needs to authorize with the user.  Either that wasn't done yet, or your API calls are wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Brad I've tested with 3 different admins for that application, Live-API doesn't work without approving.

Comment: @Maxim `publish_pages` are missing from your list. Try and add that and see if it works.

Comment: @Bangdel, unfortunately, it didn't help me.

Comment: @MaximFirsoff Are you using the Graph API Explorer app by any chance? If you are then I'd recommend trying with your own app. Also, what is the error message you are getting this time?

Answer (score 0):

The full list of permissions is and it's working for all admins/test users: "publish_actions", // user, group "manage_pages", "publish_pages", // user page "user_managed_groups", "user_friends", "public_profile", "user_actions.video" // notifications for friends